# Looking for a lifehacker type blog article

Tags: discussion, blog

A challenge for the masses:

To promote the site and the blog, I'd like to solicit ideas for a blog article that would appeal to both our audience (DIY.stackexchange) and a site with an established base that is known for linking to other content (like lifehacker.com - here's their [diy](http://lifehacker.com/diy/forum) tag).

Just ideas are welcome, but if you want to write the article - even better!

Comment: I'm confused... Isn't lifehacker just like all the sites we mark as spam when they snatch our blog entries? We've actually had somebody [answer a question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/13602/33) by linking to the lifehacker article, that linked to the question they were "answering"